# How to remove mapping to folder in TFS?

Tags: tfs, mapping

User X created workspace on my machine and mapped project to a folder. Then user X was either removed or revoked privileges to this project, but workspace was left unchanged.

Now I want to map project to this folder, but Visual Studio refuses - saying, that user X still have live mapping.

I tried to remove cache from `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\5.0\Cache`. I tried to remove files from `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces`, but neither worked - the mapping is still active.

What can I do to force remove this mapping?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TFS Side Kicks to manage other users workspaces. it allows you to remove workspaces and also to check in absent users files that are checked out.

you can get sidekicks [here](http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/)